# Basic Angular JS application not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm a beginner, I have a simple Angular JS that's not working, I don't understand why, here is my code (the two files `index.html` & `script.js` are in the same folder):

index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<body ng-app>


<p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
<p ng-bind="name"></p>

<div ng-controller="MainController">
{{message}}
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

script.js :

```
var MainController = function($scope) {

 $scope.message = "Hello";

};
```

The ng-model is working, the name that I write in the textbox gets displayed, but I get `{{message}}` instead of the actual message `Hello` that I have in the scope of the controller.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can find documentation and example [here][1]
Hope it will help.



  [1]: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Comment: I did, I still can't find why it doesn't work because it should.

Comment: First of all you have to initialize your app
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap

Comment: `ng-app` is enough to bootstrap the app, and the `ng-model` & `ng-name` are working fine, but not the `{{message}}` I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Name your app

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
```

Create an app.js

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
```

Rename script.js to MainController.js  , (Don't have to, but for a clean development)

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) { 
 $scope.message = "Hello";
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks but, I already tried it this way and it works ( and no need to rename `script.js` to `MainController.js` ) But I need a solution or an explanation of why the code that I used doesn't work, everything is working except `{{message}}`.

Comment: Prior to Angular 1.3 (when you could define controllers on the global scope), Angular was able to automatically discover controllers that were defined globally.

As of Angular 1.3, all controllers have to be defined within a module, and thus, you'd get very limited functionality out of an ng-app without a module. It could potentially be beneficial for prototyping, but even there, you're not going to get much.